# Answer verification: Power series expansion of $\frac{1}{3-z}$ and radius of convergence about $3i$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, solution-verification

Find a power-series expansion of the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{3-z}$ about the point $3i$ and calculate the radius of convergence, my attempt:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{1-(\frac z3)}\right)=\frac13\left(1+\frac{z}{3}+\frac{z^2}{3^2 2!}+\frac{z^3}{3^3 3!}+\cdots\right)$$

This has radius of convergence from $3i$ to the non-analytic point at $z=3$ correct? So then I have $\sqrt{3^2+3^2}=\sqrt{18}=3\sqrt{2}$ as the radius of convergence.

---

Is my power series expansion correct, is my radius of convergence correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your radius of convergence is correct.

One problem with the power series expansion is that there shouldn't be any factorials in the denominators in your expansion, i.e.$$\frac{1}{1-\frac z3} = 1 + \frac z3 + \frac{z^2}{3^2} + \frac{z^3}{3^3} + \cdots$$

Even if you fix this, what you have is a power series expansion about the point $0$ not about the point $3i$. To find this you should instead consider
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{3-z} = \frac{1}{(3-3i) - (z-3i)} = \frac{1}{3-3i}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-3i}{3-3i}}$$

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! So we introduce $+3i-3i=0$ into the denominator, how is this expanding around $3i$? Expanding around $z_0$ means we want to have $z-z_0$ in the denominator